How to create custom mixed data types shortcut
I have a number of functions in my code whose data type of their input arguments are basic data types. Mostly string|int|float and sometimes null|string|int|float .
public function example(string|int|float $arg1, string|int|float $arg2, null|string|int|float arg3)
{ /* ... */ }

Repeating these phrases lengthens lines and reduces readability.
Is there a keyword shortcut for basic data?
Or is there a way to define a pulpit for these cases?
Like:
BASIC = string|int|float
public function example(BASIC $arg1, BASIC $arg2, ?BASIC arg3)
{ /* ... */ }


It seems PHP does not support native aliasing of data types. The only way to achieve a similar/close functionality is through PHPDOC comments i.e.
/**
* @param string|int|float $arg
* @param string|int|float|null $arg1
*/
public function example($arg, $arg1) {}

